# Select wordpress posts in a category and group by all other categories?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, categories, wordpress

All the code samples I've seen for this involve a parent category and child cats.  However, what I have is categories like so (simplified):

```
-Towns
--NY
--Chicago
--LA
-Restaurants
-Theatres
-Stores
```

Now, I have created a page for Chicago. On it I'd like to display all the other items which match Chicago:

```
-Restaurants
--restaurant 1
--restaurant 2
--restaurant 3
-Stores
--store 1
--store 2
etc
```

How would I do this? In the template, I guess I'd have to get the slug from the URL of the current page and query that category (chicago) first, then loop the others but I'm not entirely sure how.

EDIT:  I also need to do it the other way around, Show all restaurants in the country grouped by city.

Comment: Would it make more sense to use tags? All of the restaurants would be tagged as such and under the city category.

Comment: Perhaps, but I also need category archive pages for Restaurants, grouped by city. If I figure out one, I'm hoping I can do all.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could do that on the tag template page - I'm just not exactly sure how :)

Comment: Try working with custom fields, it's easier. One custom field could be the city, for example. Another one could be the business type (Restaurant, store, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can try another approach.
Create Custom Posts Types: Restaurants, Stores, etc. Example:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'restaurants',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Restaurants' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Restaurants' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

Then you create a Page for Chicago, entries for restaurant 1, restaurant 2, restaurant 1 of type Restaurants and assigns all of them to category Chicago.

Now in the template for Chicago you can show all entries of Restaurants type that assigned to Chicago category.

```
//add this after the Loop

query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'restaurants',
    'category_name' => 'chicago', //use category slug
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
) );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
```

Also instead of `category_name` parameter you can use `cat` parameter, that takes category id.

Comment: Yes, but that still doesn't solve the question of grouping them all on the chicago page: restaurants,shops, theatres, etc. Also, I need to do the reverse, go to the restaurants page and show all restaurants by city.

Comment: Maybe i didn't understand your aim, but you can call on chicago page template `query_posts` function for each custom post type (restaurants, shops, ...). And you will get lists with posts of this types. On restaurants page template you can get all restaurants with the same code.